# How to split the string of specific format and assign it to variable in c#?

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# and would need some advice on how to approach the following problem.

I have the following.

```
string input = "{1, 'hello', 1, 3}, {2, 'othello', 0, 2}"
```

There could be cases where there is just one `{}` or more in the input string.

I want to be able to to split the input string on the two or more `{}` and create an instance of the class Data and add each of the new instances to a `List<Data> mydatalist()`.

I have the following declaration of the Data class. I am not sure on how to split the input string and create the Data class instance from it.

```
public partial class Data
{
    private:
    int id;
    string desc;
    int state;
    int res;

    public:
    Data(int idval, string indesc, int instate, int inres)
    {
        id=idval; desc=indesc; state=instate; res=inres; 
    }
}
```

In the end, my `List<Data> mydatalist()` would contain two `Data` class objects with the respective fields declared accordingly.

```
void CreateInstances(string result)
{
   var temp = result.Split(); // This gives me every index?
}
```

Any help wold be appreciated.

Comment: If that string is JSON, why don't you just deserialize it into your objects..?

Comment: `I am not sure on how to split the input string and create the Data class instance from it` this could be done many ways, please show us an attempt.

Comment: @Stuart that's not valid `json`

Comment: I mean, you could definitely write a parser specifically for this format, but what you have looks similar to JSON. If possible, I'd use JSON as there's already lots of parsers/encoders that exist for it. Like [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: That's correct @Çöđěxěŕ, but it looks like it easily _could_ be...

Comment: @Stuart how would I be able to assign the index in the input string as I deserialize? i am a bit lost

Comment: @user1538301 Could you provide me some sample please? I am very new to C# and I am not sure if I can do it without ur help

Comment: @Stuart I agree it definitely does, but indeed it's not.

Comment: @Anna Where is that string originating from? and, could you make it JSON? If so, then it will be easy to help.

Comment: @Anna we would love to help, please update your post to include what you have tried and what isn't working. As of right now, we don't have anything to go on, we could throw an answer out, but may not be what you are working with.

Comment: This is actually a json response string. I am not sure if you mean something like this JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(result) ?

Comment: @Anna it's *not* valid.

Comment: Something along those lines yes @Anna

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I updated to show the ```CreateInstances``` method. Does it make it better now?

Comment: @Anna I've gone ahead and posted an example of using JSON and JSON.NET to deserialize your Data Object.

Comment: @user1538301 Can you work on with the CreateInstances method I have shown above?

Comment: `This is actually a json response string` where ever you are getting this at is wrong, you need to talk to the other end and find out why. Of course we could wing it, but that shouldn't be the case. What if they fix this response and you've gone ahead and created a temp fix, now your stuff is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use a regular-expression for the repeating `{ <number>, <string>, <number>, <number> }` part.
- I strongly recommend using an immutable POCO instead of a mutable type as your code does.
- You said you're new to C# but I don't know if you're new to regular-expressions and parsing in genreal, but the regular-expression "matches" your input text and allows the program to extract data from it. Think of it as a more powerful form of a wildcard or glob search `"foo*.txt"` you may have seen already.

  - `(\d+)` means "match decimal digits"
  - `\s*` means "expect optional whitespace here"
  - `'(.*?)'` means "read every character between two quotes as a single value"
  - You can try it out online here: https://regex101.com/r/mesMGG/1
- The `Match.NextMatch()` method and `Match.Successful` properties allows the same regex to be run multiple times over an input string.
- The matched text are returned as `String` values in `Match.Groups[]`.

  - Note that `Match.Groups[0]` is always the whole input string, which is why my code starts at index `1` instead of `0`.
  - Because they're `String` values, you need to use `Int32.Parse` or `Int32.TryParse` to convert them to `Int32` values.

Like so:

```
class Data
{

    public Data( Int32 id, String description, Int32 state, Int32 res )
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Description = description;
        this.State = state;
        this.Res = res;
    }

    public Int32 Id { get; }
    public String Description { get; }
    public Int32 State { get; }
    public Int32 Res { get; }
}

public static List<Data> ParseData( String input )
{
    RegEx r = new Regex( @"\{\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*'(.*?)'\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\}" );

    List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

    Match m = r.Match( input );
    while( m.Success )
    {
        Int32  id    = Int32.Parse( m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
        String desc  = m.Groups[2].Value;
        Int32  state = Int32.Parse( m.Groups[3].Value, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
        Int32  res   = Int32.Parse( m.Groups[4].Value, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

        Data d = new Data( id, desc, state, res );
        list.Add( d );

        m = m.NextMatch();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Used like so:

```
List<Data> list = ParseData( "{1, 'hello', 1, 3}, {2, 'othello', 0, 2}" );
```

Comment: Wow - 2 downvotes within 30 seconds of posting! Not sure what I did wrong :S

Comment: `Not sure what I did wrong` its mature IMHO. It doesn't explain anything and isn't even explaining what the OP is even doing wrong. For someone *new* to `c#` this is definitely to broad...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Please feel free to edit my answer to give the necessary exposition if you feel my code is too hard to follow.

Comment: that's not the point, I can follow it, but are you sure the OP can?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I've added more exposition to my post.

Comment: thank you, now the OP has something they can follow to help understand  your solution.

Comment: I can get behind this answer because it *does not* treat the input as JSON. Doesn't really matter if OP thinks it is, the fact is that it is not, so it can't be parsed as such until they figure that out.

Comment: Where do you get Regex from?

Comment: @Anna `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and change your input to JSON:

```cs
string dataString = "[{id: 1, desc: "hello", state: 1, res: 3}, {id: 2, desc: "othello", state: 0, res: 2}]"
var dataObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(dataString );
```

Comment: The OP just asked for an example of this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

This deals with `dest` having spaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

(...)

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string input = "{1, 'Western Australia', 1, 3}, {2, 'othello', 0, 2}";
    var pattern = "{(.*?)}";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

    var separated = matches
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].ToString())
                .ToList();

    var os = new Program().CreateInstances(separated).ToList();
}

IEnumerable<Data> CreateInstances(IEnumerable<string> separated)
    => separated.Select(o =>
        {
            var parts = o.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
            return new Data(
                int.Parse(parts[0]),
                parts[1].Trim('\''),
                int.Parse(parts[2]),
                int.Parse(parts[3]));
        });
```

---

## Test

### Code

```
// I made fields public just to print the values
foreach(var o in os ) Console.WriteLine($"id={o.id}, desc={o.desc}, state={o.state}, res={o.res}");
```

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
id=1, desc=Western Australia, state=1, res=3
id=2, desc=othello, state=0, res=2
```

Comment: can you show how the output whould look like and can you please put this in a method as I showed above? I am getting some may errors running your code. Does it work for you?

Comment: Which assembly directive you use for the Select ?

Comment: Does this code account for `,` appearing between two `"`'s? Maybe that's not even an issue.

Comment: @tymtam please add some backing content to support your solution.

Comment: @Anna - the `Select` is a part of LINQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I get this error ```matchcollection does not contain a definition for select c#```

Comment: Added `using`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example just doing standard string manipulation w/ a few assumptions about the standardization of your data strings.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string input = "{1, 'hello', 1, 3}, {2, 'othello', 0, 2}";

        //get the first start open curly
        int start = input.IndexOf('{');

        List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
        while (start >= 0)
        {
            //find position of first close curly after our open curly
            var end = input.IndexOf('}', start);

            //get all values between curlys
            var setValues = input.Substring(start + 1, (end - 1) - start);

            //split them into array
            var split = setValues.Split(',');

            list.Add(new Data()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]),
                Desc = split[1],
                State = Convert.ToInt32(split[2]),
                Res = Convert.ToInt32(split[3])
            });

            //get next open curly based off of most recent closed curly position
            start = input.IndexOf('{', end);
        }
    }
}
    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public int State { get; set; }
        public int Res { get; set; }
    }
}
```